# insert, the json of a file, in the empty array of a json of another file

Tags: json, shell, insert, addition, jq

I would like to insert this piece of code from the devices_format.json file

```
{
  "devices": [
    {
      "name": "new_elsys",
      "objects": [
        {
          "name": "ServerRoomTemp",
          "datapoint_type": "measurement",
          "coder_field": "temperature"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "old_elsys",
      "objects": [
        {
          "name": "ServerRoomTemp",
          "datapoint_type": "measurement",
          "coder_field": "temperature"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

in the empty array of test_3.json

```
{
  "drivers": {
    "lorawan": {
      "interfaces": [
        {
          "devices": []
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The result should look like this

```
{
  "drivers": {
    "lorawan": {
      "interfaces": [
        {
          "devices": [
           {
             "devices": [
               {
                 "name": "new_elsys",
                 "objects": [
                   {
                     "name": "ServerRoomTemp",
                     "datapoint_type": "measurement",
                     "coder_field": "temperature"
                   }
                 ]
               },
               {
                 "name": "old_elsys",
                 "objects": [
                   {
                     "name": "ServerRoomTemp",
                     "datapoint_type": "measurement",
                     "coder_field": "temperature"
                   }
                 ]
               }
             ]
           }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried using jq but I wanted to know if it was possible also with jshn

I modified the post to make it clearer, thank you guys in advance and have a good day :P

Comment: Post your efforts also to the question

Comment: Please fix the data so that it is valid JSON. You could use jq to find the errors, or jslint.com, etc.

Comment: It's done! Do you have an answer?

Comment: See update.  I had not noticed you wanted [$insert].

Comment: Indeed, I want to insert the json "devices_format.json" in the empty "devices" array of "test_3.json"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach (after ensuring the data is valid JSON) would be to specify the path to the empty array explicitly:

```
jq --argfile insert devices_format.json '
  .drivers.lorawan.interfaces[0].devices |= [$insert]
  ' test_3.json
```

### Equivalently ...

```
jq -n 'input as $insert
       | input 
       | .drivers.lorawan.interfaces[0].devices |= [$insert]
  ' devices_format.json test_3.json
```

Comment: Can you add a note on the trade-off between doing this and using `input` as `+= [input]` and explain which is better?

Comment: Thank you! the first solution does not work and the second does not correspond to the desired result..

Answer (score 0):

If you want every .devices array that's empty to be replaced by the specified JSON, you could go with `walk/1`, e.g.:

```
jq -n 'input as $insert
       | input
       | walk(if type=="object" and .devices == [] 
              then .devices = [$insert] 
              else . end)
  ' devices_format.json test_3.json
```

Comment: thank you, I wouldn't want to replace every empty array, just "devices" array from test_3.json

Comment: Please see update that ensures only .devices is checked.